# Connect sql server to php using laravel "php artisan migrate "

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, database-migration

When I want to migrate user table to my database it shows me this error

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

> could not find driver (SQL: select * from sys.sysobjects where id = object_id(migrations) and xtype in ('U', 'V'))

This is my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1433
# 3306
DB_DATABASE=GestionHotel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

This is my database.php file

````
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            // 'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'),
            // 'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'true'),
        ], ```
````

Comment: Show us the application code you're using to try to run the SQL; it looks like you've put parameters in the wrong place based on that error.

Comment: i'm not using any code yet i just used the command "php artisan migrate" to migrate the user table

Comment: You are obviously doing *something*, we need to know what, as what ever the thing it is you're doing, you've put your SQL query in the driver parameter.

Comment: i used php artisan make:auth command , Now when i want to register a new user this happend

Comment: hi aymane, welcome to stackoverflow. just to be sure, `sqlsrv` (sql server driver) is properly installed and registered in `php.ini`, right?

Comment: thanks . yes it's installed and registered